# Stuck at defining relationship in laravel 4

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to understand laravel by creating a messaging application. User should be able to send message to each other. i have made a similar application using core php.

I'm done with login/authentication and migration and now stuck at defining relationship in models;

i have created 3 tables using migrations:

1. users
2. conversations
3. conversations_reply

This is the Schema of:

1. users table (For storing detail of users)

   ```
   $table->increments('id');

   $table->string('username', 50);
   $table->string('password', 50);
   $table->string('name', 50);         
   $table->string('email', 254);

   $table->timestamps();
   ```
2. conversations table(For storing conversation between users)

   ```
   $table->increments('id');

   $table->integer('user_one'); //foreign key of one friend from users table
   $table->integer('user_two'); //foreign key of second friend from users table
   $table->string('ip');

   $table->timestamps();
   ```
3. conversations_reply table(For storing Conversation text)

   ```
   $table->increments('id');

   $table->text('reply');
   $table->integer('user_id');
   $table->integer('conversation_id'); //foreign key of conversations table
   $table->string('ip');

   $table->timestamps();
   ```

Now, i'm trying to define relationships in models as:

1. `User` model wil have *hasMany* relationship with both `Conversation` and `ConversationReply` model.
2. `Conversation` will have *belongsToMany* relationship with `User` model and *hasMany* relationship with *ConversationReply* model.
3. `ConversationReply` model will have *belongsToMany* relationship with both `User` and `Conversation` model.

Now i'm stuck at defining relationship in the first model(User)and unable to proceed further because i need to define local and foreign key, but i'm unable to do so because conversations table will have 2 foreign keys(of 2 users) and i can define only one foreign key.

Edit: There should be only two members in a conversation and and two users should have only one conversation(like facebook). Their new messages should be added to their old conversations. In conversations table, ip is the ip address of the user who would start the conversation and in the conversations_reply table, ip is the respective ip of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a little flaw in your abstraction. You have actually designed user1 and user2 as *attributes* of the Conversation entity, but they are not attributes. Also, what is the IP of a conversation?

*Attributes* of a Conversation may be topic, start time, end time, amount of messages and things like that.

And then a conversation has members. Not exactly two but *many*. So you could just create an entity / model *ConversationMembers* that connects *User* and *Conversation*:

**conversation_members table:**

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('conversation_id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->string('ip');
$table->string('nickname');
```

and change the **conversations table** accordingly:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->boolean('public);
// other attributes you're interested in
$table->timestamps();
```

Now you can define the relationships on your models:

**Conversation:**

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ConversationMember');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ConversationReply');
}
```

**ConversationMember:**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function conversation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Conversation');
}
```

**User:**

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Conversation', 'ConversationMember');
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ConversationReply');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Edit: There should be only two members in a conversation and and two users should have only one conversation(like facebook). Their new messages should be added to their old conversations. In conversations table, ip is the ip address of the user who would start the conversation and in the conversations_reply table, ip is the respective ip of the user

Comment: @user170654 Ok, it actually doesn't matter how many members there are supposed to be, because that's not important on the data abstraction level. *many* means one or more. In order to indicate that a particular user has started the conversation, I don't think it's a good idea to decide that by which IP is set. Instead, you should just add another attribute like `$table->boolean('initiator');` to your conversation_members table - because that's actually an attribute of a conversation member.